# SQL - Using HASHBYTES for Encryption password but it change to Chinese words

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

I am going to use HASHBYTES() for hiding my password but when I am going to insert them into a table it changes the password to Chinese words.
my code:

```
INSERT INTO [Library].[dbo].[Supervisor]
VALUES(NEWID(), N'Abbas Jafari', '@AbbasJafari', HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'P@ssw0rd'))
```

my output:

| ID | Name | UserName | Password |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C72B34EC-6FDC-467E-9E76-766570EA7A55 | Abbas Jafari | @AbbasJafari | 봡�㼘๴濧뜧뎎誜狙垧 |

but when I am going to use this function in a SELECT statement it works well:

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'P@ssw0rd'); --output:0xB03DDF3CA2E714A6548E7495E2A03F5E824EAAC9837CD7F159C67B90FB4B7342
```

Do anyone knows what is wrong with "봡�㼘๴濧뜧뎎誜狙垧"? can I leave it like this?

Comment: Could you share description of your [dbo].[Supervisor] table? Specifically, what type is used for Password field?

Comment: sure, it is nvarchar(256)

Comment: You should really hash it client-side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your data type from nVARCHAR(max) to varbinary(max)

```
SELECT CAST(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'P@ssw0rd') as nvarchar(max))
SELECT CAST(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'P@ssw0rd') as varbinary(max))
```

or varbinary(32) if you'd prefer

Comment: `binary(32)` would make the most sense